# SearchBar not showing up in NavigationBar in Swift 4 IOS 11

Tags: ios11, swift4, xcode9

I have been trying to add Searchbar via UISearchController in my app. It does not show up on my navigation bar.I have added a navigation controller as a root view controller and have not changed anything but just the tint colour of it. I have tried few solutions but nothing works. I am using Swift 4.0 with Xcode 9 and running the app on IOS 11. Below is my code. Thanks in advance.

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        let sc = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        sc.delegate = self
        let scb = sc.searchBar
        scb.sizeToFit()

        scb.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44.0).isActive = true
        scb.tintColor = UIColor.white


        self.navigationController?.navigationItem.searchController = sc
        self.navigationController?.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false

    }
```

Comment: Did you find the solution? @waleed

Comment: @PratyushPratik No man, still haven't found the solution. What I did instead was added a searchbar to navigation controller and used its delegate methods for my needs accordingly.

Answer (score 10):

I don't know why but it will help you.

Add search controller in NavigationItem directly.

```
navigationItem.searchController = sc
navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the searchbar as your tableview header, worked for me.

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe delete `sc.delegate = self` and put instead `scb.delegate = self`.
Also, I think you have to choose only one between `scb.sizeToFit()` and `scb.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44.0).isActive = true` because one excludes the other one. Hope it helps.